# failed to install grub2

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2

I tried to dual boot ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10.i have also done it before but this time it said "failed to install grub2".after this it said installer crashed.Now i tried boot repair disk .the url it gave is " http://paste2.org/Nj1H1UJw".so what should i do now to dual boot it.

Comment: Link not working, update it again.

Comment: can u tell something without this link that what should i do

Comment: Really need lots more info. But is Windows 10 UEFI. Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. Or is Windows BIOS and your installed Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode? Grub often does not install to gpt partitioned drives as it does not have a needed support partition. If UEFI, you must have the ESP - efi system partition which Windows has already created if it is UEFI. And if BIOS you must have the bios_grub partition. But then you often are mixing UEFI with WIndows & BIOS boot with Ubuntu. Best to have all systems in same boot mode.

Comment: my windows is in bios. now please tell me how can i dual boot ubuntu..

Comment: Pastebin is now obsolete, post a new one.